# Simple Objective-C over-release that *should* crash is not crashing. Why?

Tags: objective-c, debugging, memory-management, crash, foundation

Either my debugger is broken or there's something fundamental that I am not understanding.

I have some very basic code in a very basic command line program that **should** crash. However, it is not crashing.

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"];

    [string release];

    NSLog(@"Length: %d", [string length]);

    return 0;
}
```

The log statement prints "Length: 5" as you would expect for a valid string. However, the string should be deallocated by that point and an `exec_bad_access` error should be thrown.

I have tried this code with the debugger attached and without the debugger attached - both give the same result. I have also enabled (and disabled) `NSZombie`, which seems to have no effect (I initially thought this was the problem, since `NSZombie` objects are never deallocated - but it still does not crash with `NSZombie` disabled).

I have breakpoints set in my local `.gdbinit` file to break on things such as `-[NSException raise]` and `objc_exception_throw`. I also have breakpoints set on many methods on `NSZombie` in order to catch them.

```
fb -[NSException raise]
fb -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:]
fb -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]

#define NSZombies
# this will give you help messages.  Set to NO to turn them off.
set env MallocHelp=YES
# might also be set in launch arguments.
set env NSZombieEnabled=YES
set env NSDeallocateZombies=NO
set env MallocCheckHeapEach=100000
set env MallocCheckHeapStart=100000
set env MallocScribble=YES
set env MallocGuardEdges=YES
set env MallocCheckHeapAbort=1

set env CFZombie 5

fb -[_NSZombie init]
fb -[_NSZombie retainCount]
fb -[_NSZombie retain]
fb -[_NSZombie release]
fb -[_NSZombie autorelease]
fb -[_NSZombie methodSignatureForSelector:]
fb -[_NSZombie respondsToSelector:]
fb -[_NSZombie forwardInvocation:]
fb -[_NSZombie class]
fb -[_NSZombie dealloc]

fb szone_error
fb objc_exception_throw
```

With these breakpoints set and NSZombie enabled, I should get something like `[NSString length]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x100010d39` printed to the console, but I do not see this. I see the `NSLog` printing the length as 5.

I see similar behaviour with other classes such as `NSURL` and `NSNumber`. But some classes crash as expected, such as `NSError` and `NSObject`.

Does this have something to do with class clusters? Do they not follow the same rules in regards to memory management?

If class clusters are not related to this problem, the only other common feature I could see was that the classes which don't crash in this way are all toll-free bridged with a Core Foundation counterpart. Could this have something to do with it?

Comment: I've been wondering myself this a while ago, saw the same 'problem'/behavior. Hope someone can explain this.

Comment: Garbage collection is not instant? :)

Comment: That's not the point. In the garbage collected environment, an explicit call to `release` does absolutely nothing.

Comment: This is not in a garbage collected environment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`retain`/`release` is a contract between the API and the programmer that when you follow the rule, it doesn't crash. The contract doesn't guarantee that if you doesn't follow the rule, it does crash!

In this case,

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"]
```

just returns the same object as `@"Hello"` as an optimization. The constant `NSString` is never deallocated; as an optimization, `retain` and `release` are (I think) ignored. That's why it doesn't crash.

You can check my guess by comparing the pointer value of `@"Hello"` and `string`.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense to me. What about if I did `[[NSString alloc] init];` as opposed to initing with a constant string? In my testing, it still exhibits the same behaviour as using the constant string, is this expected too? And what about the other cases where I see the same behaviour, such as with `NSURL` and `NSNumber`?

Comment: And yes, you are correct, string and @"Hello" both point to the same location. That clears that up. I'm still confused about the other cases though.

Comment: `[[NSString alloc] init]` returns a shared empty string, which is again never destroyed. There's no guarantee that each call to `[[SomeClass alloc] init]` gives a distinct instance. The contract is that if you follow the retain/release rule, the program doesn't crash. Nothing more than that.

Comment: @Jasarien `[[NSString alloc] init]` is short-circuited to `@""`.  WRT `NSNumber`, the numbers for 0-12 are singletons.  Not sure about `NSURL` though...

Comment: It might help your understanding to do `NSLog(@"%@",[anObject class]);` to every object you create. You clearly see that the framework uses a specialized classes to very common instances as an optimization.

Comment: Ok that clears up most of the things. I understand the contract between API and programmer to guarantee not crashing. I just stumbled across this while purposefully trying to make the program crash to test my debugger breakpoints, and was completely thrown when it didn't crash...

Comment: When doing such experiments, you should generally subclass `NSObject` (or, if feeling ambitious, create your own root class and try to make it work with Foundation) so you can control all the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent example of why retain counts are a pretty useless debugging tool.  It is a mistake to assume -retain and -release always add or remove 1 from the retain count and that the retain count is what you think it should be.

Try

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello %d", argc];
```

That should give you a string that will behave more like the way you are expecting since you are not initialising your string from a compile time constant.  However, be warned, with zombies enabled, you'll get the behaviour you expect but without zombies, the NSLog may well work.   Although the string has been deallocated, the data in the object is still there in memory leaving a "ghost" that will respond correctly to some messages.